# Spring security is not working in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway, java-17

I am trying to configure spring gateway using spring boot 3 version, java 17 version, and kotlin language.
However, it seems that the spring security settings are not applied.

as postman

POST
If I call it with http://127.0.0.1:11001 I get a 403 Forbidden error and An expected CSRF token cannot be found
The result is

Regarding this, I already created a SecurityConfig class and set it as below, but it doesn't work.

The github address used for this configuration is as follows:
https://github.com/arubear1321/studyspringgateway.git

If I configure it with the same java version, it works fine.
I don't think there's anything special to set, so why doesn't it work?

---

SecurityConfig.kt

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain


@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig::class.java)

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        logger.info("Configuring SecurityWebFilterChain")

        http
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .authorizeExchange {
                it.anyExchange().permitAll()
            }
            .formLogin{ it.disable() }
            .httpBasic{ it.disable() }

        return http.build()

    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 11001
  shutdown: graceful

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 60s
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - OPTION
              - PUT
      routes:
        - id: api
          uri: http://127.0.0.1:11002
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**

logging:
  level:
    root: TRACE
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
```

Comment: If I configure it with the same java version, it works fine.